# initialRouteName of react-navigation does not work as expected

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am using react-navigation v5, I have the following code to open the screen based on if user is logged in or not.

```
<Stack.Navigator
        
        initialRouteName={phone?.length>0 ? data?.accountType === 1 ? "Seller" : data?.accountType === 0 ?  "Buyer" : "SignIn": "SignIn"}
        headerMode="screen"
        screenOptions={{
          headerShown: false,
        }}>
..........
 </Stack.Navigator>
```

And the phone data and data?.accountType is coming from AsyncStorage inside my **componentDidMount()** . This is done to open Seller/Buyer page when he is already logged in or SignIn page when he is not logged in. But it always takes me to SignIn page. Is it that before the **componentDidMount()** gets me the data from AsyncStorage, initialRouteName is already run and thus both phone and data?.accountType are null?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is simple way you can achieve the result like

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      initialRouteName: null,
    }
  }

  render() {
    const layout = this.Layout(this.state.initialRouteName);
    return (layout);
  }

  /** Layout */
  Layout =(initialRouteName)=> {
    if (initialRouteName !== null) {
      return (
        <NavigationContainer>
          <MainStack.Navigator initialRouteName={initialRouteName}>
            <MainStack.Screen name={"screen1"} component={screen1} />
            <MainStack.Screen name={"screen2"} component={screen2} />
          </MainStack.Navigator>
        </NavigationContainer>
      );
    } else {
      return (<View></View>);
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({initialRouteName: condition ? "screen1" : "screen2"});
  }
```

Comment: Thanks a ton, this indeed helped. Just need to figure out is a better option to show in the else block instead of a white screen.